# Activiti user tasks

Tags: java, workflow, activiti, bpmn

I have been looking all over the Internet and I haven't found a solution for what I want to do.

I am new to BPMN (I read a book but I still have doubts) and I have to correct a project at work. The project uses the Activiti framework version 5.12.

Currently, there is a diagram made which has certains relations and lots of User tasks. Nowadays, there are some tasks that move from one user to another. The other day a client told me he needed the user to receive an email when a task arrive. The thing is they do not want me to change the process itself (I considered changing the user task into an email task or something like that). So I looked over the internet if its possible to set to the user task an option to send an email to the user as soon as a task arrives.

The project is made in Java (7).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is an ideal opportunity to add a listener to the user task.
The listener can be on either task creation or task assignment (doesnt really matter which) and calls a simple class that will send the email.

If you prefer not to create a class that sends an email, you could create a second process that is started by a signal start event and have your listener send the signal event.

Using either option, the diagram will not change and if you write your listener generically enough it can be used on any task the user wants a notification for.

We have implement this pattern many times.

Cheers,
Greg Harley - BP3